Is it possible to trigger a #if macro if two or more definitions are defined?
For instance, imagine you want to enable only one compilation target so you do something like this:
// uncomment ONE of these #defines to compile for a specific target
#define TARGET_1
#define TARGET_2

#if !defined(TARGET_1) && !defined(TARGET_2) // none defined
#error "You MUST select a target platform in target_platform.h"
#elif defined(TARGET_1) && defined(TARGET_2) // too many defined
#error "You must select ONLY ONE target platform target_platform.h"
#endif 

This works fine. And the #if scales well.  However this second conditional in the #elif doesn't scale well to multiple targets as the conditional logic starts to get very complex.  Thus, is there a way to scale this with some #if condition that we can check if at least two or more are defined for the second case?  For instance, if I had 10 targets, this becomes very cumbersome to write, update, and maintain if I have to manually write all the conditional logic(or worse, someone else has to come back and understand it later)
I've tried looking at the syntax of #if, #elif, #define, Defined(), #ifdef, and #ifndef, but not of them seem to lend themselves to a cleaner way of doing this?  At least, not that I can think of.  But #if has gotten me the closest.

so like #elif defined(TARGET_1) + defined(TARGET_2) + defined(TARGET_3) > 2 ? Much better solution would be to make users choose explicitly #define TARGET TARGET_1.

It's not really possible. You need ti list all "targets" in both conditions. Possibly you could make a script that checks this at build-time.

Apparently we aren't allowed to bake in defined in other macros, so something like an X-macro list isn't possible. It would likely be best to generate this out of an external script indeed.

defined is an operator that evaluates to 0 or 1, so all you need, if you stll want this rather than Brad Lanam’s method is:
…
#elif 1 < defined TARGET_1 + defined TARGET_2 + defined TARGET_3 + …
    #error "You must select ONLY ONE target platform in target_platform.h"
#endif

You could actually combine both tests:
#if 1 != defined TARGET_1 + defined TARGET_2 + defined TARGET_3 + …
    #error "You must select EXACTLY ONE target platform in target_platform.h"
#endif


I would be inclined to write it as:
#if TARGET_1
# if defined (TARGET_SELECTED)
#  error "Target is already selected"
# endif
# define TARGET_SELECTED 1
/* other target-1 stuff */
#endif

#if TARGET_2
# if defined (TARGET_SELECTED)
#  error "Target is already selected"
# endif
# define TARGET_SELECTED 1
/* other target-2 stuff */
#endif

...

#if ! defined (TARGET_SELECTED)
# error "No target has been selected"
#endif

This makes it quite straightforward to add a new target, just copy/paste a block, rename the target, and fix up any target specific values.
